# How to append #rss to each RSS feed item's URL built with Views?

Tags: views, feeds

### Problem

**I have an RSS feed built with Views on a Drupal 7 installation. I want to append the following string to each feed item's URL but don't know how: "#rss"**

For example, let's assume my RSS has a feed item linking to a blog post

http://www.example.com/blog/post.html

I would like to add the hashtag to the end of it, so I get

http://www.example.com/blog/post.html#rss

### Why?

*This hash tag will allow me to see who is visiting the site from my RSS feed* as it'll appear on my Analytics program.

I could use Feedburner or other 3rd party feed tracking alternatives, but I am purposefully staying away from them, for reasons we don't need to go into.

Anyhoo, I only managed to get the Views RSS to work recently and have no idea how to modify the feed item URL. Can anyone help? Please assume I am a novice at this.

Comment: you need to rewrite the url in your rss view

Comment: @rémy sorry but how do I rewrite the URL?

Comment: in that view - how do you link to the node ? there should be options - one named rewirte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the RSS view, look at the format section. If you're like me, you'll have the following

**Format:** RSS feed
**Show:** Content

[image]

1. **Make sure to switch "Content" to "Fields"**, otherwise you won't ever see the "rewrite" options that the commentators keep mentioning above. Add all the necessary fields you'll need for the RSS feed.  You should get something like this (Ignore the field Hardcoded...)

   [image]
2. Now, click on the "Content:Path" field (which you should've added), expand the "Rewrite Results" section, and **tick the "Rewrite the output of this field" checkbox**.
3. **In the provided textbox, add your custom URL parameter.** In my case, I wanted a hashtag, so I added the following:

   ```
   [path]#rss
   ```
4. **And, you're done!** You may be asking, how did you know what to put in that textbox? Scroll down a bit and expand the "Replacement Patterns" section. You can add all types of stuff. I found this [post](http://highrockmedia.com/blog/rewriting-drupal-views-output-custom-theming-css) useful. Of course, I discovered it after I had solved the problem. Still good to know.

Feels good solving my own problem, though special thanks to Remi who pointed me in the right direction.

It *seems* pretty obvious after the fact and maybe that's why no one wanted to actually write out an answer but for beginners like me, it's obscure. Anyway, I wrote this out in detail in the hopes you won't get stuck here. Hope it helps :)